# Can't import zfs pool after power loss

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I was in the middle of rsyncing some files onto a zfs mirror pool, and we lost power due to a storm.  Now after starting the machine the pool won't import:

```
sudo zpool import
   pool: share
     id: 16927970099329697736
  state: ONLINE
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier.
 config:

        share                                          ONLINE
          mirror-0                                     ONLINE
            usb-ST8000DM_004-2CX188_152D00539000-0:2   ONLINE
            usb-ST8000DM_004-2CX188_152D00539000-0:3   ONLINE
          mirror-1                                     ONLINE
            usb-ST8000AS_0002-1NA17Z_152D00539000-0:0  ONLINE
            usb-ST8000AS_0002-1NA17Z_152D00539000-0:1  ONLINE

sudo zpool import share
cannot import 'share': I/O error
        Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source.
```

Same goes for zpool import -fF share

fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x84d19b36

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 960239615 960237568 457.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       960241662 976771071  16529410   7.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       960241664 976771071  16529408   7.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 TiB, 8001562869760 bytes, 15628052480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F7FAF7CA-0A09-4593-99F3-09117657ABCB

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 15628050431 15628048384  7.3T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdc: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 56DB49CC-9FBA-314C-B58B-79C764207B17

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1         2048 15628036095 15628034048  7.3T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdc9  15628036096 15628052479       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdf: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2B77FF7F-0FDA-3A47-B481-7F42325E2DF3

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdf1         2048 15628036095 15628034048  7.3T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdf9  15628036096 15628052479       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdd: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A59B15EF-DE16-C54B-A60A-4B7D1528DF25

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1         2048 15628036095 15628034048  7.3T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdd9  15628036096 15628052479       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sde: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ECCC4E5A-32F8-2744-AB9E-430B5511DB3A

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1         2048 15628036095 15628034048  7.3T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sde9  15628036096 15628052479       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1
```

Comment: USB disks? Your ZFS pool is made of USB disks?!?